# Can't login to phpmysql in wamp also issues with sessions

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I have actually two issues connected to each other. The sessions was not passed over between pages in Wamp but working perfectly on the server. 
if i change the session.auto_start to 1 in Wamp then the sessions passed over correctly but i can't login to phpmyadmin. If i change the session.auto_start to 0 then phpmyadmin let me in, but the sessions are not passed over between pages in wamp. It drives me mad, especial because it worked with no issue before with the exact same website. (i didn't change anything in the website and it works on the server) 
session settings in php.ini (wamp):

```
[Session]

session.save_handler = files
session.save_path ="c:/wamp64/tmp"
session.use_strict_mode = 0
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 1440
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain = ".localhost."
```

Version numbers in Wamp:
WampServer Version 3.0.6 64bit
Apache 2.4.23 - PHP 5.6.25 - MySQL 5.7.14

[More info]
I fill some sessions on one page like $_SESSION["blabla"]=1 and redirect to another subpage, all of my sessions are empty but the sessionID is set so sessions are working.

When i try to login to phpmyadmin the page just reload without any error message.
The only message i get is on the console:

"Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'nonce-D411CCD8134EE540AE24AC502C54039F' http://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com ws://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-Znx9+G9zA+tuD8Jhp366cVvHMKX3f6akSB6VwBQDw0o='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution."

I tried to switch kapersky off completely then the message doesn't come up but still can't login.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "not passed over" and "can't login"?  What is the specific operation you're performing and what is the specific error you're getting?

Comment: Do you start a session_start in pages actually ?

Comment: yes as it worked perfectly before. this is a 7 years old website and i didn't change it for at least 2 years. Now i tried to change but i ran into these problems before i even touched the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it's fixed. If anyone else experiencing same issues:
I downloaded the latest version of PHPMyAdmin from their site and updated in Wamp.
Seems the version older than 4.9 can have security issues which caused the invalid login.
That solved the problem.